# How to sort data in R

Tags: r

So lets say I have data that comes from an excel spreadsheet like:

```
S96-A44 | Meox1
S96-A45 | Irx3
S96-A42 | Pax6 
S94-A01 | Puit
S91-A33 | Itf4
S95-A56 | Lit5
```

And I wanted to sort them like this, where the sample goes down and the assay goes up:

```
S96-A42 | Pax6 
S96-A44 | Meox1
S96-A45 | Irx3
S95-A56 | Lit5
S94-A01 | Puit
S91-A33 | Itf4
```

What would be the best way to do this. I know the question is a little vague and if you need me to clarify more I can, Thanks.

Comment: Use the `order`  function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible combined `tidyr` and `data.table` solution. It seems like you want to sort the data by two parts of single column and then sort the data by two different orders. Here we first separate the first column into two columns and then reordering the data. (I'll assume your data called `df` and the columns are `V1` and `V2`)

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
setorder(separate(setDT(df), V1, c("sample", "assay")), -sample, assay)[]
#    sample assay    V2
# 1:    S96   A42  Pax6
# 2:    S96   A44 Meox1
# 3:    S96   A45  Irx3
# 4:    S95   A56  Lit5
# 5:    S94   A01  Puit
# 6:    S91   A33  Itf4
```

Answer (score 1):

With data.table versions `1.9.5+`, you can use the function `tstrsplit()`, which is very similar to base function `strsplit()`, except that it transposes the list that is returned from `strsplit()`.

And that helps to assign the columns directly within data.table, as follows:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5
setDT(df)[, c("sample", "assay") := tstrsplit(V1, "-", fixed=TRUE)]
setorder(df, -sample, assay)
df[, V1 := NULL] # removes V1
```

`setDT` converts `df` to a data.table. The `:=` function adds the two columns obtained to `df` and names them `sample` and `assay`.

Then we *reorder* the columns by `sample` in decreasing and then `assay` in increasing order.

You can install the development version `1.9.5` from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).